# BEGIN(INITIAL) in flex parser

Tags: flex-lexer, text-parsing

I have a flex question. I cannot understand what `BEGIN(INITIAL)` command is. I think this is the way to go to the start of the current state that I am already in, but I am not sure if I got it correct. Can you explain to me in simple terms what `BEGIN(INITIAL)` does?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: after `BEGIN(INITIAL);`, it's like "forget the token we're in, we're gonna scan the next token."

Comment: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cr4bd/flex-manual/Start-Conditions.html first several paragraphs should enough to figure this out.

Comment: @alandawkins It's always like that after a token was found. `BEGIN` operates on start conditions, not on tokens.

Answer (score 8):

It brings to back to the initial state. Say you have something like:

```
%x FOO
%%

[A-Z]    { BEGIN(FOO); }
.        {}
<FOO>.   {}
<FOO>\n  { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
%%
```

Here the initial state, i.e. the state INITIAL is the state that matches against the first two patterns, i.e. the "default" state. If you read any upper case character, you'll end up in state FOO. In state FOO, if you encounter a newline you will end up in the initial state, which is again the state that matches the first two rules.

Answer (score 0):

`BEGIN` changes the current start condition in the lexer.
Start conditions are a way of choosing which rules are currently used by the lexer and which ones are ignored. In a way, they allow creating multiple lexers in one, which may (or may not) share some of the rules.

This is useful if you want temporarily change the lexer's behavior.
For example, you've encountered a beginning of a string and now you want to scan for escape sequences instead of normal keywords.
You can create a start condition that does that and switch to it at the beginning of a string, then switch back when you encounter the end of the string.

The macro `BEGIN` chooses which starting condition will now be used.
`INITIAL` is just an integer constant - the ID of the start condition that is active by default.
(Simpler scanners don't have other start conditions. In that case you don't need to worry about `BEGIN` at all.)